# $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of an open Ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $$A_n = \mathbb{B}\left(\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right),1\right) \ , \ \forall n \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

I don't know How can I calculate $\limsup A_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\liminf A_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ of this set $A_n$?

I have that $$A_1 = \mathbb{B}((-1,0),1)$$
$$A_2 = \mathbb{B}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right),1\right)$$
$$A_3 = \mathbb{B}\left(\left(-\frac{1}{3},0\right),1\right)$$ etc..

For a sequence of subsets $A_n$  of a set $X$, the $\limsup A_n= \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \left( \bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n \right)$ and $\liminf A_n = \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \left(\bigcap_{n \ge N} A_n\right)$.

But How can I calculate this in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Could someone help me to solve and understand this, pls...

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably aware of the following characterizations:

$$x \in \limsup_n A_n \iff x \in A_n \text{ for infinitely many } n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$x \in \liminf_n A_n \iff x \in A_n \text{ for all except finitely many } n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I claim that $\liminf_n A_n = B((0,0),1)$ and $\limsup_n A_n = \overline{B}((0,0),1) \setminus \{(0, \pm 1)\}$.

Indeed, for any $(x,y )\in B((0,0),1)$ we have that $$d\left((x,y), \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right)\right)^2 = \left(x - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 + y^2 \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} x^2 + y^2 < 1$$

so there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$n \ge n_0 \implies d\left((x,y), \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right)\right)^2 < 1 \implies (x,y) \in A_n$$

This shows that $B((0,0),1) \subseteq \liminf_n A_n, \limsup_n A_n$.

Now take any point $(x,y) \in \partial B((0,0),1)$ which is not $(0, \pm1)$. We will show that $(x,y) \in \limsup_n A_n$.

Indeed, if $x > 0$, for even $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

$$d\left((x,y), \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right)\right)^2 = \left(x - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 + y^2 = \underbrace{\left(x - \frac1{n}\right)^2}{} + y^2 < x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

so $(x, y) \in \limsup_n A_n$.

For odd $n \in \mathbb{N}$ however, we have:

$$d\left((x,y), \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right)\right)^2 = \left(x - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 + y^2 = \underbrace{\left(x - \frac1{n}\right)^2}_{>1} + y^2 > 1$$

so $(x,y) \notin \liminf_n A_n$. Analogously we would prove it for $x < 0$.

So, $$\partial B((0,0),1) \setminus \{(0, \pm 1)\} \subseteq \limsup_n A_n$$

For any $(x,y) \notin \overline{B}((0,0),1)$, similarly we have:

$$d\left((x,y), \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right)\right)^2 = \left(x - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 + y^2 \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} x^2 + y^2 >1$$

so there exists $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$n \ge n_1 \implies d\left((x,y), \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right)\right)^2 > 1 \implies (x,y) \notin A_n$$

For $(x,y) = (0, \pm 1)$ we have:

$$d\left((x,y), \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right)\right)^2 = \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 + y^2 \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^2}+1 >1$$

so $(x,y) \notin \liminf_n A_n, \limsup_n A_n$.

This shows that $\liminf_n A_n, \limsup_n A_n \subseteq \overline{B}((0,0),1) \setminus \{(0, \pm 1)\}$. We also previously showed that elements of $\partial B((0,0),1)$ are not in $\liminf_n A_n$ so $\liminf_n A_n \subseteq B((0,0),1)$.

Hence, $\liminf_n A_n = B((0,0),1)$ and $\limsup_n A_n = \overline{B}((0,0),1) \setminus \{(0, \pm 1)\}$.

Comment: why $B((0,0),1) \subseteq \liminf_n A_n, \limsup_n A_n$ ?

Comment: I am curious where my comment went? This answer is not correct, the point $(1,0)$ is in the $\limsup$.

Comment: @copper.hat I see my mistake now: if $x^2+y^2 = 1$, then there doesn't exist an $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the distance is $\ge 1$. It seems that $(\pm,0) \in \liminf A_n, \limsup A_n$ but I'm not sure how to prove that there is nothing else.

Comment: I dont erase any comment, why comment @copper.hat?

Comment: Yea I´m trying to prove this but it´s so hard, I can't prove it.

Comment: The $\limsup$ contains all points in the closed unit ball except for $(0,\pm 1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah, just realized that. I'm trying to prove it.

Comment: @Knight I've made a few edits, have a look now.

Comment: Ok, I sorry just for curiosity, why $(1,0)$ is in lim sup?

Comment: @Knight Because $(1,0) \in A_n$ for every even $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$d\left((1,0), \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},0\right)\right) = 1 - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}  = 1 - \frac1n < 1
$$

Comment: this is valid only for lim inf, isn't it?  $B((0,0),1) \subseteq \liminf_n A_n, \limsup_n A_n$ not for lim sup

Comment: @Knight Why not? It's valid for both. Note that this always holds: $$\liminf_n A_n \subseteq \limsup_n A_n$$