# Can anyone explain me why I need to assume algebra here?

Tags: measure-theory

There is one definition of outer measure which is acceptable:

[image]

I have confusion that why we need $A_0$ necessary to be algebra here. We can also consider $A_0$ as $\sigma$ algebra
on $\Omega$ and proof will be gone as the same we did with algebra.
If not, then can anyone explain me why?

Comment: (Out of topic sorry) @vatsy I was posting an answer, could you undelete the question, please?

Comment: @VIVID I got my answer on this link

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518627/limsup-and-liminf-of-an-open-ball-in-mathbbr2

Comment: Ok, good. Please, research more before posting a question next time. Otherwise, some people may just waste their time trying to write an answer to the question that is going to be deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction goes back to Carathéodory; in some texts, this construction is called "Method I".

This will be OK where $\mathcal A_0$ is any family of sets.

Some authors will require at least that there is some countable cover of $\Omega$ by sets of $\mathcal A_0$; but others will say the inf of the empty set is $+\infty$ and proceed anyway.

Note your definition says $\mu_0(\varnothing) = 0$, so it requires $\varnothing \in \mathcal A_0$.  You can avoid this by replacing the formula for $\mu^*$ to allow all countable covers: not only indexed by $\mathbb N$, but also finite or even empty covers; and use the convention that an empty sum is $0$.  Then you recover $\mu^*(\varnothing) = 0$.

An extreme case is $\mathcal A_0 = \varnothing$.  Then we do not need $\mu_0$ at all, and we get $\mu^*(\varnothing) = 0$ [from the empty cover] and $\mu^*(E) = +\infty$ for all nonempty sets $E \subseteq \Omega$ [because no countable covers of $E$ exist].

Comment: I got that. Thanks @GEdgar